# IDictionary<string, string> or NameValueCollection

Tags: c#

I'm currently writing an interface to allow applications to send exception data to a central repository for support purposes. I'm at a quandary about how to pass extra contextual data:

```
public interface IExceptionNotifier
{
    void Notify(Exception ex, NameValueCollection context); //this      
    void Notify(Exception ex, IDictionary<string, string> context); //or this
}
```

I've often found myself is a similar position when creating lookups. Ignoring whether or not the exception notifier concept is good, is it be best to use an `IDictionary<string, string>` or `NameValueCollection`? Why would you pick one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the context is a throw-away value and (here comes the important part) will not be serialized, e.g. for sending the data to another system, I'd go with the IDictionary because it makes using your interface more flexible.

If, on the other hand, the context is kept all the time or the context will be serialized, use NameValueCollection because then you are under control of what you'll actually get from your caller.

Edit: mausch is right in that you should use a generic approach, but I still wouldn't use an interface if you want to serialize the data.

Comment: Could you expand on "under control of what you'll actually get from your caller"? Is the possibility of a caller sending duplicate keys the issue? I guess I'm not quite understanding why you'd avoid a dictionary if serialization is involved.

Comment: @JeffBridgman: This was almost ten years ago, I don't actually remember what I meant ;)
I guess it's about getting an object of a specific class (i.e. with certain constraints like serialization support), or getting *anything* with a certain interface. For example, the IDictionary implementation may just not support serialization or some methods, while NameValueCollection is a fixed implementation, so it depends on what you want to do with the context. Note that there are several other questions about this on SO with interesting discussions.

Answer (score 5):

(Assuming .NET 3.5 here. Pre .NET 3.5, NameValueCollection would have the benefit of being able to tie multiple values to a key, with no direct equivalent in "normal" collections.)

Do you want keys to have potentially multiple values? If so, I'd consider ILookup<TKey, TValue>. Otherwise, I'd go for IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.

Aside from anything else, if the receiver wants to do any processing where LINQ would be of use to them, either of the generic interfaces is going to be nicer than NameValuePair. Likewise, it may be easier for the caller to produce a dictionary/lookup using LINQ if they've already got a generic or dynamic kind of context.