# Generic form of NameValueCollection in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Does .Net provides generic form of NameValueCollection or an alternative to
`Dictionary<string,List<T>>` ?

Something like

```
Person john = new Person();
...
Person vick = new Person();
...

NameValueCollection<Person> stringToPerson = new  NameValueCollection<Person>();
stringToPerson.Add("John",john)
stringToPerson.Add("Vick",vick)
```

Actually in my case am forced to rely on `Dictionary<string,List<Peron>>`, is there any other alternative?

Regards,
Jeez

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144516/idictionarystring-string-or-namevaluecollection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing built in to the BCL as far as I know. I would just write your own class which wraps a `Dictionary<string, List<T>>` internally and exposes appropriate methods (e.g., `Add` could add an element to the `List<T>` for the given key).

For example:

```
class NameValueCollection<T>
{
    Dictionary<string, List<T>> _dict = new Dictionary<string, List<T>>();

    public void Add(string name, T value)
    {
        List<T> list;
        if (!_dict.TryGetValue(name, out list))
        {
            _dict[name] = list = new List<T>();
        }

        list.Add(value);
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The closest alternative is probably the [**`ILookup<TKey, TElement>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291.aspx) interface. At the moment, the only public type that implements it in the BCL is the immutable [**`Lookup<TKey, TElement>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) class, an instance of which can be created with the [**`Enumerable.ToLookup`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) method. If you want a mutable type that implements the interface, you'll have to write one yourself; you can find an example implementation [here](http://gitorious.org/cadenza/cadenza/blobs/44dc5bd09fba58681eae052fc3fda3718fd77cc7/src/Cadenza/Cadenza.Collections/MutableLookup.cs).

In your case, you probably want an `ILookup<string, Person>`.

Comment: Yeah but I think the OP wants to be able to *add* to the collection; `Lookup<TKey, TValue>` is too restrictive for this purpose, since it is read-only.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I see what you want to do now. You want to be able to add to the Person collection without having to create a new List each time. Extension methods to the rescue!

```
public static void SafeAdd<TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, ICollection<TValue>> dict, TKey key, TValue value)
{
     HashSet<T> container;
     if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out container)) 
     {
         dict[key] = new HashSet<TValue>();
     }
     dict[key].Add(value);
}

Usage:
var names = new Dictionary<string, ICollection<Person>>();
names.SafeAdd("John", new Person("John"));
```

Comment: nothing wrong Josh, was just looking for something better and readable

Comment: @Jeez, I didn't know what you wanted. I do now. Check out my answer, I think you'll find it a lot easier than reimplementing every method on IDictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing inbuilt; there is `Lookup<TKey,TValue>` which operates as a multi-map, but that is immutable. I wrote a mutable `EditableLookup<TKey,TValue>` for [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) which may help.

Answer (score 0):

## Generic NameValueCollection

What makes **NameValueCollection** special unlike **Dictionary**, is that one key can contain several elements.

The generic **NameValueCollection<**T**>** based on **NameObjectCollectionBase** is in the following code:

```cs
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace System.Collections.Generic
{
    public class NameValueCollection<T> : NameObjectCollectionBase
    {
        private string[] _keys; // Cached keys.
        private T[] _values;    // Cached values.

        // Resets the caches.
        protected void InvalidateCachedArrays()
        {
            _values = null;
            _keys = null;
        }

        // Converts ArrayLit to Array of T elements.
        protected static T[] AsArray(ArrayList list)
        {
            int count = 0;
            if (list == null || (count = list.Count) == 0)
                return (T[])null;
            T[] array = new T[count];
            list.CopyTo(0, array, 0, count);
            return array;
        }

        // Gets all values cache.
        protected ArrayList GetAllValues()
        {
            int count = Count;
            ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(count);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                arrayList.AddRange(Get(i));
            }
            return arrayList;
        }

        // Adds single value to collection.
        public void Add(string name, T value)
        {
            InvalidateCachedArrays();
            ArrayList arrayList = (ArrayList)BaseGet(name);
            if (arrayList == null)
            {
                arrayList = new ArrayList(1);
                if (value != null) arrayList.Add(value);
                BaseAdd(name, arrayList);
            }
            else
            {
                if (value == null) return;
                arrayList.Add(value);
            }
        }

        // Adds range of values to collection.
        public void Add(NameValueCollection<T> collection)
        {
            InvalidateCachedArrays();
            int count = collection.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                string key = collection.GetKey(i);
                T[] values = collection.Get(i);
                foreach (var value in values)
                {
                    Add(key, value);
                }
            }
        }

        // Set single value (prevoious values will be removed).
        public void Set(string name, T value)
        {
            InvalidateCachedArrays();
            BaseSet(name, new ArrayList(1) { value });
        }

        // Set range of values (prevoious values will be removed).
        public void Set(string name, params T[] values)
        {
            InvalidateCachedArrays();
            BaseSet(name, new ArrayList(values));
        }

        // Gets all values that paired with specified key.
        public T[] Get(string name)
        {
            return AsArray((ArrayList)BaseGet(name));
        }

        // Gets all values at the specified index of collection.
        public T[] Get(int index)
        {
            return AsArray((ArrayList)BaseGet(index));
        }

        // Gets string containing the key at the specified index.
        public string GetKey(int index)
        {
            return BaseGetKey(index);
        }

        // Removes values from the specified key.
        public void Remove(string name)
        {
            InvalidateCachedArrays();
            BaseRemove(name);
        }

        // Removes all data from the collection.
        public void Clear()
        {
            InvalidateCachedArrays();
            BaseClear();
        }

        // All keys that the current collection contains.
        public new string[] Keys
        {
            get
            {
                if (_keys == null)
                    _keys = BaseGetAllKeys();
                return _keys;
            }
        }

        // All values that the current collection contains.
        public T[] Values
        {
            get
            {
                if (_values == null)
                    _values = AsArray(GetAllValues());
                return _values;
            }
        }

        // Values at the specefied index.
        public T[] this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return Get(index);
            }
            set
            {
                BaseSet(index, new ArrayList(value));
            }
        }

        // Values at the specefied key.
        public T[] this[string name]
        {
            get
            {
                return Get(name);
            }
            set
            {
                BaseSet(name, new ArrayList(value));
            }
        }

        // Enumerates all entries.
        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, T>> GetAllEntries()
        {
            foreach (string key in Keys)
            {
                foreach (T value in Get(key))
                {
                    yield return new KeyValuePair<string, T>(key, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage:

```cs
NameValueCollection<int> collection = new NameValueCollection<int>();
collection.Add("a", 123);
collection.Add("a", 456); // 123 and 456 will be inserted into the same key. 
collection.Add("b", 789); // 789 will be inserted into another key.

int[] a = collection.Get("a"); // contains 123 and 456.
int[] b = collection.Get("b"); // contains 789.
```

The above code implements the main features.
[Here](https://github.com/ng256/NameValueCollection) is  complete implementation of the **NameValueCollection<**T**>** with additional tools.